# Fonts not loading in parallel loaded styles

Tags: css, fonts, parallel-processing

I am currently setting up parallel loading on many sites using one same code base and I am having issues with fonts not being loaded in the styles.

Here is how it is setup:

.htaccess:

```
# Images / Styles / Scripts rewrites
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(images\.)?([^.]+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(styles\.)?([^.]+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(scripts\.)?([^.]+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=DOMAIN_SEGMENT:%2]
```

In the head

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://styles.test.com/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Where `test.com` is replaced by the actual domain for the current site.

In the stylesheet

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Aller';
    src: url('/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#Aller') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
}
```

Many sites using the same code base, it is not possible to hard set the domain for the fonts within the CSS.
All the fonts were loading fine prior to the parallel change.

The rest of the style-sheet is being loaded correctly.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the font was trying to be loaded from `styles.test.com/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot` and therefore not loading.

A solution was to use this in my .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply this

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Aller';
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#Aller') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
}
```